# Pass JSON as javascript variable in pug

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, pug

I want to pass an array of objects into my javascript code block but I am struggling because it would html encode the result so that I've got a lot of `&quot;` in my actual JSON.

Basically my router gets the JSON object from the redis store and I am trying to pass it to the template:

```
redis.getBuffer('languages', function (err, result) {
    res.render('manager/create-project', { title: 'Create Project', breadcrumbs: req.breadcrumbs(), languages: result })
})
```

I assign it like this to my variable:

```
script.
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var languages = #{languages};
```

**The problem:**
The actual javascript variable languages gets the html encoded string as shown below.

```
var languages = [{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;aa&quot;,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;Afar&quot;}]
```

How can I properly pass my JSON content to the javascript block?

Comment: Can the one who downvoted this question explain me why he did so? Maybe I can improve my question then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to interpolate without escaping. This can be achieved by using `!` instead of `#`.

For example, changing your template to the following should solve your issue:

```
script.
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var languages = !{languages};
```

For reference, here's the link to the [docs](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html)

Comment: Perfect, I wasn't aware of that!

Comment: Glad to help! Most template languages auto-escape HTML chars to prevent unintended code execution (like script tags in a comment), thus it's good to know how to have control when needed

Comment: It does not work at all, if `languages` is a JSON, PUG stringifies it also if called with `!` syntax

Answer (score 5):

The working way to do that is (I know is horrible but PUG works like this)

```
script(type="text/javascript").
    $(document).ready(function(){
       var languages = !{JSON.stringify(languages)}
    });
```

Working on 2018

More info on http://www.mircozeiss.com/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-from-a-server-to-angular

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

**NodeJs**:

```
res.render('itemdetails', {
    title: 'Donation item details',
    user: req.user,
    item: item.toJSON(),
    GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY: process.env.GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY
  });
```

**Pug View**:

```
 script.
  $(document)
    .ready(() => {
    createGlobalObjects('minimap');
    let item = !{JSON.stringify(item)};
    initLocationSearch(positionItemOnMap.bind(item));
  });
```

**Results:**

[image]